# get own anchor href values

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, joomla3.0

Please see my code below . I want to fetch href value from the html. I have create a logic for that like first count all the divs and then fetch all values one by obe but problem is the there is not any unique class or Id and i want fetch one by one.

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    var mylength = jQuery(".jr-layout-outer").length;
    console.log(mylength);
    for (i= 1; i <= mylength ;  i++) {
      var aa = jQuery(".jr-layout-outer .jrListingContent .jrListingThumbnail a").attr("href");
      console.log(aa);

    };


    });
</script>


  <div class="jr-layout-outer"> 
    <div class="jrListingContent">
              <div class="jrListingThumbnail">
                    <a href="index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=3">
                      <img class="jrMediaPhoto" title="" alt="" src="reviews/photos/thumbnail/120x120c/a3/5e/bc/m-mustermann-54-1401265222.png">
                    </a>
              </div>
    </div> 
  </div>

  <div class="jr-layout-outer"> 
    <div class="jrListingContent">
              <div class="jrListingThumbnail">
                    <a href="index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=3">
                      <img class="jrMediaPhoto" title="" alt="" src="reviews/photos/thumbnail/120x120c/a3/5e/bc/m-mustermann-54-1401265222.png">
                    </a>
              </div>
    </div> 
  </div>

  <div class="jr-layout-outer"> 
    <div class="jrListingContent">
              <div class="jrListingThumbnail">
                    <a href="index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=3">
                      <img class="jrMediaPhoto" title="" alt="" src="reviews/photos/thumbnail/120x120c/a3/5e/bc/m-mustermann-54-1401265222.png">
                    </a>
              </div>
    </div> 
  </div>

  <div class="jr-layout-outer"> 
    <div class="jrListingContent">
              <div class="jrListingThumbnail">
                    <a href="index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=3">
                      <img class="jrMediaPhoto" title="" alt="" src="reviews/photos/thumbnail/120x120c/a3/5e/bc/m-mustermann-54-1401265222.png">
                    </a>
              </div>
    </div> 
  </div>

  <div class="jr-layout-outer"> 
    <div class="jrListingContent">
              <div class="jrListingThumbnail">
                    <a href="index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=3">
                      <img class="jrMediaPhoto" title="" alt="" src="reviews/photos/thumbnail/120x120c/a3/5e/bc/m-mustermann-54-1401265222.png">
                    </a>
              </div>
    </div> 
  </div>

  <div class="jr-layout-outer"> 
    <div class="jrListingContent">
              <div class="jrListingThumbnail">
                    <a href="index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=3">
                      <img class="jrMediaPhoto" title="" alt="" src="reviews/photos/thumbnail/120x120c/a3/5e/bc/m-mustermann-54-1401265222.png">
                    </a>
              </div>
    </div> 
  </div>

  <div class="jr-layout-outer"> 
    <div class="jrListingContent">
              <div class="jrListingThumbnail">
                    <a href="index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=3">
                      <img class="jrMediaPhoto" title="" alt="" src="reviews/photos/thumbnail/120x120c/a3/5e/bc/m-mustermann-54-1401265222.png">
                    </a>
              </div>
    </div> 
  </div>
```

I want to get anchor tag href attribute in Id.
Is this possible we will create a make only javascript not change in the divs or class because all are in Ioncube code.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. It would help if you showed your existing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map()` in jquery to get the all href value in array

```
 var aa = jQuery(".jr-layout-outer .jrListingThumbnail a").map(function () {
           //console.log($(this).attr("href"));  see in console
            return $(this).attr("href");
    }).get();

alert(aa);
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Bala_chandran/w09ovpkp/)

Comment: Can we split only id from the href and append a button in  every after "jrListingContent" div with this id that we have split. in anchor tag.

Comment: @PriteshMahajan id should be unique  it is cmg  3 for all

Comment: @PriteshMahajan this is you need http://jsfiddle.net/Bala_chandran/w09ovpkp/1/ check and tel me

Answer (score 0):

This might go into comment but can't format it correctly in comment. If only thing you want to get all href which are inside div which has class jr-layout-outer, then this should do it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('.jr-layout-outer').find('a').each(function () {
            console.log($(this).attr('href'));
        })

    });
```